# Web API Parameter Path Too Long

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm making this call to a Web API method:

```
var url = rootWebApiUrl + '/api/services/files/' + $scope.selectedServer.Name + "/" + encodeURIComponent(fullPath) + '/';

$http.get(url) // rest of $http.get here...
```

Because the `fullPath` variable is long, I get a `path too long` error on the PhysicalPath property in a framework method that we have:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath.Length > 0)
    return ApplicationConfigurationWeb;
```

So I thought perhaps I could do something like this to pass the data, but I can't seem to get the call to hit the right Web API method:

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/services/files',
    params: { serverName: $scope.selectedServer.Name, path: fullPath }
}

$http(req)  // rest of get here...
```

Is that an appropriate alternative to get larger data to a Web API method? If so, how should my url be constructed to get the right method? If not, how can I get past this `path too long` issue?

This is the Web API method signature:

```
[Route("api/services/files/{serverName}/{path}")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<FileDll> Files(string serverName, string path)
```

Comment: If you are starting to mess with huge URLs, it's almost always better to POST the data in the body instead.

Comment: I'd love to do this the right way. Do you have an example of how to do what you suggested? By the way, the URL isn't huge; it's just over the limit.

Comment: Well "over the limit" is pretty big :) I'll dig out an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your updated call, 'params' should end up being the query string, so if you updated your webapi route to this:

```
[Route("api/services/files")]
```

And added this attribute to the `httpRuntime` node in the `system.web` section of your web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
```

I believe it should start working

**EDIT**

As DavidG mentioned, a more appropriate way would be to post the data instead of using a get.  To do so, you'd change your request config to this:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: rootWebApiUrl + '/api/services/files',
    data: { serverName: $scope.selectedServer.Name, path: fullPath }
}
```

Then update your Route like so:

```
[Route("api/services/files")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<FileDll> Files(FileData myData)
```

Where FileData would be a class that looks something like this:

```
public class FileData
{
    public string serverName { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This worked. If there isn't a more appropriate way, like @DavidG's answer, I'll accept this one. Thanks!

Comment: thunder stealer is my super hero name

Comment: I'll still give you a +1 though :)

Comment: Why is the POST option a better way? Is it because the parameters are in the body instead of the URL?

Comment: The URL wasn't intended to contain a ton of data, which is why you were running into problems (the browser could limit it, your server could limit it, anything in between could limit it).  I'm not aware of any limits on how much data you can put in the body of a request